# What is the reason of sound from the attached file?

Tags: macos

From time to time I hear this sound without any visible notification: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwUf1IftWc6YUk1BWDFoQ1A2SW8/view

What is the reason of it?

Usually I have the following apps opened: Chrome, Skype, Telegram, Sublime Text, IntelliJ, iTerm, Commander One, Postman.
macOS 10.12.3

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's Skype, either someone logging in or leaving a message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

James P, Thanks for the hint! It was Skype indeed.

To turn off this sound I went to Skype -> Preferences -> Notifications -> Overview and unchecked "Play sounds related to contact availability"